# Laravel unknown status with Slack integration

Tags: laravel, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to implement [Slack Actions](https://api.slack.com/actions) in slack with Laravel as endpoint.

In Slack, I made the setup of the request URL as well as registering an action.
The button appear in Slack.

With laravel I made a simple route for testing the slack-payload like this

```
Route::post('slack-payload', function( $payload ){
    dd( $payload );
})->name('slack-payload');
```

But when I press on my custom-action, on the laravel side I received a `419 unknown status`.

I'm guessing it's because of the `token` missing from Slack that Laravel want. So I added my route in the `$except` of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'slack-payload'
    ];
}
```

But now I'm having a `500 Internal Server Error` ...

Comment: Check the logs of either laravel or the server to check what is going on. There must be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: In my function I excepted a `$payload` but I need a `Request $request`. My bad.